# What does “provisionally” charged with the case of negligent homicide mean?

Tags: meaning

AP reports on July 28 that “the driver of a Spanish train that derailed at high speed killing 79 people was **provisionally charged** Sunday with multiple cases of negligent homicide.”
http://world.time.com/2013/07/27/spain-train-driver-suspected-of-negligent-homicide/

Oxford English Dictionary defines “provisionally” as;

adverb - subject to further confirmation, for the time being: ex. the film, provisionally entitled Skin, is due to be released next year

Is it possible that the train driver in question who is responsible for the deaths of 79 people was charged with negligent homicide only “*subject to further confirmation, just for the time being*” loosely in face of the deadly disastrous scene and fact obvious to public eyes?

What does “**provisionally** charged with a case” exactly mean?
What are legal implications of 'provisional charge'?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It's seen as highly likely that the charge will be changed, but provisionally charging him means they can hold him and question him. Of course, the charge has to be reasonable; Spanish police aren't allowed to just go around provisionally charging anyone they want to hold for a while.

Answer (score 3):

I think there are two possibilities here.

First, different countries have different laws and procedures about when and how they can detain 'suspects' in custody and at what point in or before the detention they have to charge them. A *provisional charge* could be a standard step in the Spanish legal procedure, and even then it could be a loose translation of the Spanish terminology.

Secondly, and maybe additionally, as @JonHanna has intimated, it could be that they are awaiting further information and evidence before deciding on the final charge, which could perhaps eventually be more serious or less serious depending on the outcome of investigations.

Comment: Could it be a simple as the possibility of some of the injured dying in hospital?

Comment: There are already several dozens of confirmed dead. The question is not of life or death, but of accidental or negligent.